# Problem with degenerate triangles and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, gl-triangle-strip

I'm trying to draw multiple triangle strips with only one call to `glDrawElements` and my research on the matter tells me I need to use degenerate triangles. Maybe my understanding on the subject is wrong but I thought this should allow me to "jump" from a strip to another.

My whole code for this can be found on [this recent question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773803/hard-time-understanding-indices-with-gldrawelements), take a look there if you think it's relevant.

I'm basically trying to draw 2 quads(for simplification purposes) with 4 triangles of course, but separated from each other. For that I use indices like this:

```
unsigned int indices[] = { 0, 256, 1, 257, 257, 2, 2, 258, 3, 259 };
```

The first vertex of the first strip starts at 0 and the first vertex of the second strip starts at 256. This is the end result of this indices:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q3FD.jpg]

Is this correct or am I right in thinking that line "connecting" the 2 quads shouldn't be there at all?

Comment: Note that if you run on an OpenGL 3.1 capable card, you can use primitive restart to the same effect, but with less trouble. It works by inserting a special (unused, configurable) index that makes the GL start a new primitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image shown is correct.  This trick doesn't work for wireframes.  If you were drawing filled triangles, the triangle with zero area wouldn't show up, but you're drawing outlines.

Comment: Interesting, it's true lol. The wire-frame was just for testing purposes, it's easier to see if the mes is well built, I was just unaware of this little quirk.